# Why does this animation have a delay only after the first step?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

After each animation completes, I move the div to the end of the children list. Only after the first `complete` function is run, there's a delay before the next animation runs. After all other ones, there's no delay.

Why does the first one have a delay?

https://jsfiddle.net/cev2Lh9w/

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="test">
test
</div>
<div class="test">
test
</div>
<div class="test">
test
</div>
<div class="test">
test
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
jQuery( document ).ready(
function()
{
window.doms = document.querySelectorAll(".test");
window.self = document.querySelector( ".outer");
window.currentTile = doms[ 0 ];
window.currentMove = 0;
window.numberToMove = 20;
window.tileHeight = 20;
window.currentIndex = 0;
console.log( self );
moveNext();
});

function finishMove()
    {
        //Move the top tile to the end
        self.appendChild( currentTile );

        //Adjust its top
        currentTile.style.marginTop = "0px";

        //The next tile
        var next = doms[ currentIndex ];

        //Update current move and tile
        currentMove++;
        currentTile = next;

        //Change the current index
        currentIndex = ( currentIndex === doms.length - 1 ) ? 0 : currentIndex += 1;

        //Move again
        if ( currentMove < numberToMove ) moveNext();

        //We're done
        else alert( "done" );
    }

    function moveNext()
    {
        //Animate the sliding
        jQuery( currentTile ).animate(
            {
                marginTop: "-" + tileHeight + "px"
            },
            {
                duration: 200,
                queue: false,
                complete: finishMove
            }
        );
    };
```

Comment: I know this doesn't help much, bu if you change the code `window.currentIndex = 0;` to `window.currentIndex = 1;` that delay does not show up. I'm still not sure why. But it seems to be related to that first element of the array, though...

Comment: @n0m4d I'm not sure why but see my answer for how I fixed it. It is odd though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the building of the jQuery wrappers. If I cache them in an array and then use that array's jquery objects, there's no delay.

https://jsfiddle.net/cev2Lh9w/1/

```
//Save them as jQuery objects
window.jDoms = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < doms.length; i++ ) jDoms.push( jQuery( doms[ i ] ) );

...

//Call animate on the pre-build jQuery object
jDoms[ currentIndex ].animate(...)
```

Comment: Good point! Still, if you start from the second element the "fluidity" in the animation looks much more "natural" . Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cev2Lh9w/2/) fiddle to see my point.

Comment: @n0m4d that's really odd. I want to know why, but can't think of a reason